# Procedure for truncate and insert in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table- Event_name.

```
  select *  from Event_name
```

I have to truncate the data and insert fresh data daily.

Can someone tell me how to write a stored procedure for truncating and inserting data into table-Event_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure myProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'truncate table Event_name';    
    insert into Event_name select * from Event_name;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

The generic approach is

```
Create procedure proc_name
as
Begin    
Truncate table Event_name;
insert into Event_name(col_list)
select col_list from source_table;
End;
```